# Is there a way to vectorize this Matlab/Octave code

Tags: matlab, vectorization, octave

```
Y=zeros(length (y),10)
for c=1:length(y)
Y(c,y(c))=1
end
```

Where y is a column vector containing integers from 1 to 10

Comment: In other words: your code is already vectorized. You are just repeating it a lot of times, but each time, its already vectorized.

Comment: @AnderBiguri sorry I wrote k instead of c in the loop variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use linear indices:

```
Y=zeros(length (y),10)
c=1:length(y)
indices=sub2ind(size(Y),c.',y(c));
Y(indices)=1;
```

Comment: y(c) should be y because sub2ind takes vectors as 2nd and 3rd arguments and c should be c' as y is a column vector while c is row vector. Thanks for the answer

Comment: I will mark it as the correct answer after your edits.

Comment: @BaidyanathKundu `y(c)`  is a vector, but as you say, its irrelevant for this case. In your question, there is no way to know if `y` is row or column because you have not shared that information. I will leave this unedited.

Comment: Please read the question as I have mentioned that y is a column vector below my code  from the start  and since y is a vector y(c) is an element not a vector.

Comment: @BaidyanathKundu remember to always provide a [mcve]. Edited for your satisfaction.